# Python: np.nanpercentile, which datatype does my dataframe need to have?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentile

I have a panda dataframe of type object.

```
df.dtypes

Out:
data        object
stimulus    object
trial       object
dtype: object

df.head()

Out:
    data    stimulus    trial
0   2      -2           1
1   2      -2           2
2   2      -2           3
3   2      -2           4
4   2      -2           5
```

I want to get a specific percentile of my dataset. When I use this code, I get NaN in my output, probably because I have NaN in my dataset itself, which python interprets as infinity, so it will get problems when calculating higher percentiles.

```
df.groupby('stimulus').data.apply(lambda x: np.percentile(x, q=66))

Out:
stimulus
-2.00     2.0
-1.75     2.9
-1.00     1.0
-0.75     1.0
-0.50     0.0
 0.50     7.8
 1.00     9.9
 1.25    11.9
 1.75    13.9
 2.50     NaN
```

I already found out that I would need to use np.nanpercentile() instead, but when I use np.nanpercentile() instead then I get this error. I read somewhere else that np.nanpercentile() checks the data format of the input array and complains if it doesn't fit. Do you know how and to which format I need to change my data?

```
df.groupby('stimulus').data.apply(lambda x: np.nanpercentile(x, q=66))

Out:
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: Can you just convert the data to a numpy array and then apply np.nanpercentile to it? Like Arr = df.as_matrix(column_number) and then np.nanpercentile(Arr,66)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the job for me in the end:

```
df = df.astype(float)
```